# Drawing a resource image on to a buffered image

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedimage

Okay, I want to create a copy of an image I have in my resource folder, and put it onto the desktop pretty much. Example: My project has a resource folder with an image called apple.png. Since when I export my jar file it can't find it, I want to copy it to the desktop so it can find it from there. Here is what I tried doing:

```
try {
        // retrieve image
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(256, 256,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        File outputfile = new File(
                "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

This just created the buffered Image for me on my desktop. How do I take my res Image and copy it to it.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason for loading it as an image? If you just want to copy resource to desktop without changing it:

```
InputStream resStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png"));

//Improved creation of output path:
File path = new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")), "Desktop");
File outputFile = new File(path, "saved.png");

//now write it
Files.copy(resStream, outputFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `BufferedImage` as the image file.

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/apple.png"));));
```

All the other steps are the same.

Comment: It's a resource file though.